# Что такое "инвективная лексика"?

Tags: лексика

Хотелось бы узнать, что такое "инвективная лексика" и откуда появилось это понятие.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Инвективная (оскорбительная) лексика — лексика, унижающая честь и достоинство другого лица, выраженная в неприличной форме, которая контрастирует с принятыми в обществе нормами; может быть использована словесно или письменно. 
Вероятно, как и все современные заимствования , из английского. В английском invective - брань, ругательства.